# Cloudy plastic material

Tags: texturing

Any idea on how to make that kind of cloudy plastic?
[image]

I've tried to add subsurface to the principled BSDF texture but im not fully convinced by the result. Any thought?
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: This is definititely subsurface scattering. The lighting is important though, since the effect is dependant on the position, direction, color and intensity of the lights in your scene. Also, you can teweak the subsurface radius if you want certain effects

Comment: Thank you so much @Gorgious

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by Gorgious you should use *Subsurface Scattering*. Here I've tried with a *Subsurface* value of 1 and with a *Radius* setting of R = 2.5, G = 1.3 and B = 1. It's probably easier to get the desired effect in Cycles but in Eevee I cheated with a bit of *Emission*, otherwise it would have looked a bit too dull. Also, give it a bit of bump:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you for this answer ! It looks amazing !